# Layerslider 6 Callback Events

Tags: jquery

I checked the documentation on callbacks here: https://layerslider.kreaturamedia.com/documentation/​ but  it says that I should use the events on the sitebuilder. (Which I cannot access since I have the jQuery version of the plugin).
I only want an example on how should I use callbacks on the jQuery version.

I've been trying stuff like this with no sucess:

```
$('#layerslider').layerSlider({
autoStart: true,
firstSlide: 1,
skin: 'borderlesslight',
showCircleTimer: false,
slideChangeDidStart: function(element) {
    console.log('function called');
}
```

});

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are relying on jQuery's event handling functions, so they are fully compatible. You should use the .on() function for bind events.

```
    // Binding event
    $('#slider').on('slideChangeDidStart', function(event, slider) {
        // Your code ...
    });

    // Initializing the slider
    $('#slider').layerSlider({
        // Your settings ...
    });
```